# Web browser control WP8 using ram reduce on close view

Tags: windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

i use in my application a webbrowser control.
i use the control for navigate to many site and when i close the view, the memory is not reduced. 
Always remains on 50/60 MB.
it is possibile reduce memory?

i'm insert

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await MyWebBrowser.ClearInternetCacheAsync(); 

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

    }
```

but not it works.

Comment: First of all, is this really a problem? 50-60MB seems acceptable to me and shouldn't affect performance too much. Also, you could try to entirely remove the `phone:WebBrowser` control from the page tree.

Comment: could it be when I use certain features of the app that require memory

Comment: What exactly uses 50-60 MB by the way? The whole app or just the browser?

Comment: when I open the view with the web browser